# problem returning a json encoded response after jQuery POST in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I am having problems receiving response after using jQuery post. The script I am creating posts the data correctly and inserts correctly to the database however when I try and return a json encoded response no data is received.

Here is the code I am using:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     success: function(data) {
            if (data)
            {
            alert("DATA RECEIVED");
            }
            },
          data: {action: 'create', section: JSON.stringify(values)},
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
            url: "fields/sections/create" 
        });
```

In my controller I have

```
$section = json_decode($this->input->post('section'));


            $this->load->model('mdl_fields');


            $section_id = $this->mdl_fields->create_section($section->name, $section->row);

            if($section_id) {

                $data=array(
"section" => $section_id,
"confirm" => 'Section Has Been Created Successfully'
);
return json_encode($data);
}
```

I have checked there is a $section_id and I have printed json_encode($data) to check it is correct, which it is, but I am still not receiving a response.

I have been tearing my hair out trying to solve this for the last few hours so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you look in firebug at the response and copy it here?

Comment: @david - There is no response in firebug that is the problem. If i use `print_r(json_encode($data);` instead of `return json_encode($data);` The following is shown :

`{"section":50,"confirm":"Section Has Been Created Successfully"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you simply need to make something like

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

that would generate plain output of $data structure in JSON compatible format. Take a look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it return string and does NOT produce any output!

Answer (score -1):

Try : `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: Jason's my cousin. JSON's my friend.